# Binary searching overflows when run with large files

Tags: c

```
void insert_tree(tree_t *tree, void *name, void *movie){
    node_t *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    assert(new!=NULL);
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    strcpy(new->movie, movie);
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    insert_node(&(tree->root), new);
}

typedef struct node node_t;
struct node{
    char name[128];
    char movie[422498];
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *root;
} tree_t;
```

Code above inserts nodes to a binary search tree. I have been having thing trouble of overflowing while running the binary search tree algorithm with large files with more than 200000 lines.

With the

```
assert(new!=NULL)
```

statement, I found that the overflow is occurring in this part of the code.

I'm guessing that it is due to too many nodes being created?

How could I resolve this?

I haven't used `realloc` and `malloc` anywhere except in this part of the code.

All of the other codes also do not implement recursion they all use loops.

When the file is small enough it works perfectly with precision when it get larger it fails.

Comment: Add the definition of `node_t` to the question, por favor.

Comment: What do you mean "overflows"? Do you mean crash? `malloc` returns NULL? Wrong results? etc?? What is the exact behaviour?

Comment: `char movie[422498]` and `strcpy(new->movie, movie);` is suspicious and wasteful.

Comment: it crashes which i think is due to overflowing of memory by the malloc

Comment: Well, as mentioned in another comment your node size is huge. About 400k per node. At 200000 nodes you would need about 8GB of memory. What you should probably do is make `movie` a `char *` and dynamically allocate that memory to be just enough to hold each string. `strndup` can do that for you.

Comment: why the ridiculously large `movie` array? also why is name and movie declared as `void*` in your insert_tree function, you anyway treat them as char* inside...

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to make your nodes a bit more space efficient, having such a large array for a movie name (?) is a waste.

Instead declare the structure like this

```
struct node 
{
  char* name;
  char* movie;
  nde_t* left;
  node_t* right; 
};
```

then in your insert function:

```
void insert_tree(tree_t* tree, const char* name, const char* movie)
{
    node_t *new = NULL;

    // to catch unexpected arguments
    assert( tree != NULL && name != NULL && movie != NULL );

    new = malloc(sizeof(node_t)); // i prefer this style for sizeof

    // don't use assert for runtime errors
    if (new!=NULL)
    {
      new->name = strdup(name); // short form for malloc/strcpy
      new->movie = strdup(movie);
      new->left = new->right = NULL;

      insert_node(&(tree->root), new);
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "out of memory");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

You should later free the memory for name and movie for each node.